# How to detect the playpause button click on mediacontroller in android

Tags: android

1.What steps I will reproduce the problem?

I tried to detect the playpause button in android default media controller, I can able detect the seek bar changes (get the seeking video position) using

```
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                long cuntPost=mp.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

2. I also tried to implement the Mediacontroller.MediaPlayerControll interface  this is also not work, how can I listen the playpause button in media controller which listener I can use?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            //play next // repeat // shuffle?
        }
    });

    Button lButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    lButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //play or pause logic
            if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            else
            {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });
    //call to check current state
    mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the UI not by yourself, you can refer to MediaController api.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

Which gives you a UI and a Control object to control the MediaPlayer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html